# CloudSQL instance has less storage usage after importing

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I have a CloudSQL instance (PostgreSQL) with 112.7 GB data in it:

[image]

I wanted to transfer the data in this instance to another one.

I did an export first and then created another instance and imported the data there.

All went good. However, the resulting instance has less storage usage, only 102 GB:

[image]

No errors found in the logs. I am wondering where the 10GB data went.

Is this expected?

Comment: I think this is expected. In MySQL it is called [fragmentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-file-defragmenting.html). A similar phenomena occurs in PostgreSQL, you can read about it in [this link](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/37321/postgres-backup-restore-restored-database-much-smaller) and in [this](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Introduction_to_VACUUM,_ANALYZE,_EXPLAIN,_and_COUNT#Vacuum_the_Dirt_out_of_Your_Database)

Comment: @VictorHerasmePerez Thank you. If you post it as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: Done. thanks for letting us know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused due to fragmentation in the table. In the case of [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-file-defragmenting.html):

> One symptom of fragmentation is that a table takes more space than it
>   “should” take. How much that is exactly, is difficult to determine.
>   All InnoDB data and indexes are stored in B-trees, and their fill
>   factor may vary from 50% to 100%. Another symptom of fragmentation is
>   that a table scan such as this takes more time than it “should”
>   take:...

In the [PostgreSQL docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/routine-vacuuming.html) (see the section **23.1.2. Recovering Disk Space**), it is explained:

> In PostgreSQL, an UPDATE or DELETE of a row does not immediately
>   remove the old version of the row. This approach is necessary to gain
>   the benefits of multiversion concurrency control (MVCC, see [Chapter
>   13](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/mvcc.html)): the row version must not be deleted while it is still potentially
>   visible to other transactions. But eventually, an outdated or deleted
>   row version is no longer of interest to any transaction. The space it
>   occupies must then be reclaimed for reuse by new rows, to avoid
>   unbounded growth of disk space requirements. This is done by running
>   VACUUM.

Also read the [Vacuum the Dirt out of Your Database](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Introduction_to_VACUUM,_ANALYZE,_EXPLAIN,_and_COUNT#Vacuum_the_Dirt_out_of_Your_Database) doc in order to see steps to overcome this.

Hope this helps.